# Restrict community users visibility

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a customer portal community so that users can automatically create and update their accounts,contacts information. However, in Record List, the user can still be able to view other accounts/contacts existing on our existing Salesforce platform.

Is there a way to restrict users' views, so that they can be able to see only their accounts and contact on community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the sharing settings of account and related objects must be made private for external users.

Then you can define sharing sets in community to open up the access to allow community users to see/view records related to their account.